# Finding $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}+1} $

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, closed-form

As the question says,

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}+1} $$

where a is a constant, $a>0$.

Comment: Isn't it $n\to\infty$?

Comment: yeah, sry bout that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. We assume $\ln a \neq0$. One may use the Riemann sum result, as $n\to \infty$, giving
$$
 \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}}{a^{1+\frac{k}{n}}+1}  \to\int_0^1\frac{a^{1+x}}{a^{1+x}+1}dx=\frac1{\ln a}\int_0^1\frac{(a^{1+x}+1)'}{a^{1+x}+1}dx.
$$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: I can certainly do the latter part, but I have trouble visualizing this Riemann sum as an integral. It might be that I have an insufficient understanding of the Riemann sum. So, which part is the f(ck) and delta x?

Comment: I see, thank you very much.

Comment: @midnight2903 You are welcome.

Comment: @midnight2903 You can define $x_{k} \equiv {k \over n}$ and $\Delta x \equiv  x_{k + 1} - x_{k} = 1/n$ such that $n\Delta x = 1$. The sum becomes ${1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\,\mathrm{f}\left(k \over n\right) = {1 \over n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\,\mathrm{f}\left(x_{k}\right)\,n\Delta x =  \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\,\mathrm{f}\left(x_{k}\right)\,\Delta x$ which is closer to what you have in mind.